# How to use a custom Controller in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have a view file that is rendered from the default `SiteController`. This view file makes an ajax call to an action `getdetails` in a different controller called `A1Controller`. I want to know how to write the url in the ajax call and if there is anything that has to be changed in the `UrlManager` in web.php configuration file.

This is my ajax call :

```
ajaxCall = function () {
    $.get('how/to/write/this/url?', function (data) {
       var jsondata=JSON.parse(data);
        GenerateTable(data);
        setTimeout('ajaxCall()', 5000);
    });
};
```

Can someone help me out please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the view file:

```
<?php

$ajaxUrl = \yii\helpers\Url::to(['controller/action-name']);

$this->registerJs("
    ajaxCall = function () {
    $.get('$ajaxUrl', function (data) {
       var jsondata=JSON.parse(data);
        GenerateTable(data);
        setTimeout('ajaxCall()', 5000);
    });
};
");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is though, I've seperated the javascript code to a seperate file and added in the js folder. Is there a way around it?

Comment: @RedBottle in PHP: `$this->registerJs("var AJAX_URL = $ajaxUrl;");`
in Js: `$.get(AJAX_URL, function (data) { ...`